# MS Ajax Toolkit now on backburner?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The reason for the title is the last update of the toolkit happened on August of 2008.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16488

Is Microsoft not interested in supporting this product anymore? I just found a nasty bug that caused 2 days of hair pulling that should have been fixed years ago regarding the tabs.

Does anyone have insight into their future releases/bug fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Source Control](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) tab, you'll see that the project has been pretty active. The bug fix you're looking for might have been checked in sometime between August and Now.

I would suggest going through the check-ins or check out a copy of the latest source and try it out.

Comment: Are these builds stable? Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: I've noticed that there are a lot of codeplex projects which haven't had an actual release in while which have still had a lot of activity.  Latestly, I've been forgoing the Downloads tab and going straight to the Source Code tab to get something.

Comment: @chopps, unfortunately there is no guaranteee that the bits are stable, they probably either aren't stable, or haven't been fully tested yet. Otherwise, they would probably have released a new build.

Comment: @chopps, the new release is available: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/13/new-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx